# Is it alright to use swap function to swap elements?

Tags: c++, swap

I know that sounds silly but I am not quite sure about this because our teacher told us that we should swap element like that

```
int a=3, b=1, tmp;  
tmp=a;  
a=b;  
b=tmp
```

and not like that

```
int a=3, b=1;  
swap(a,b);
```

Could you tell me what's bad about using the function `swap` for swapping variables

Comment: Are you sure he said that? That makes no sense.

Comment: There is no reason not to use it when it is practical to do.

Comment: `std::swap` is better because it is more verbose and may enable additional optimizations.

Comment: Odds are this is an instructor trying to teach you to do it the hard way first or a complete misunderstanding.

Comment: @BaummitAugen yeah, I am sure, he said exactly that

Comment: @Tinkman `std::swap` does exactly the same thing, as the "correct swapping". You most likely misunderstood what he said.

Comment: What was the context of his statement?  What was the topic of your lesson?

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't quite remember that, it was quite a long time ago, about swapping I guess. I just wanted to make sure that using of swap will not cause problems in the future like as a habit of using "using namespace std;"

Comment: BaummitAugen, Jake Freeman, OutOfBound, user4581301, Paul Rooney, Algirdas Preidžius, PM 77-1, thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of three scenarios is true.

- `std::swap` is literally identical to the example code your teacher provided, because the canonical implementation of `std::swap` is just `A temp = std::move(a); a = std::move(b); b = std::move(temp);`
- `std::swap` is *better* code than the example code your teacher provided because some objects can optimize swaps without needing to move the whole object 3 times.
- `std::swap` is worse because, since the `std::` prefix wasn't specified, there's a chance the call to `swap` is picking up an ADL'd version of the function that is some horrific code that doesn't actually do what it claims to do. (ex: `void swap(A & a, A & b) {a.val += 15;}`)

Scenario 3 is theoretically possible, but extremely unlikely. If your teacher hasn't expressly suggested that that is what's happening, then it's probably not a scenario worth considering. So we're left to deduce what the teacher intends based on the first two scenarios.

In those situations, since `std::swap` is basically always going to be better or exactly as good, my only conclusion is that your teacher either expects a scenario where `std::swap` will be inaccessible to you, or else is simply trying to explicitly teach you how to implement `swap` yourself.

Or possibly your teacher is bad at their job. Assume the former explanations first, though.

Comment: Another possibility is the instructor was warning of the classic swap macro bug.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing bad about `std::swap`, in fact the first approach to swapping can even be *wrong* in certain cases.  For example `std::unique_ptr` has a deleted copy-constructor, so you cannot copy it to a temporary and back.  The `std::swap` function on the other hand works just fine.

```
#include <memory>

struct A {};

int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_unique<A>();
    auto b = std::make_unique<A>();

    // Does not work!
    // Copy constructor is deleted.
    std::unique_ptr<A> tmp;
    tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;

    // Works just fine.
    std::swap(a,b);
}
```